# Using ML for simple rule based to obtain likelihood

Tags: machine-learning, probability, classification, random-forest, data-mining

Let's say I already have a simple rule which provides me the variables that help determine the output label and relationship between variables and label is rather simple and deterministic one, can I still go ahead and build ML model for the below reasons?

a) Automation

b) Rank the outcomes based on their probability outcome than have a binary yes or no based on rule based system?

What do you think? Is it worthwhile do use simple random forest algorithm to do the above task?

Our users want the likelihood than a hard yes or no. Every user has different opinion on how to rank them.

And it would be close to impossible to bring the users to a conclusion on how to rank them based on their busy schedule.

So, as a objective measure, can't we use ML to get probabilistic predictions though the label is generated using simple rule-based system?

Answer (score 1):

There isn’t a probability of falling into a particular category. There are hard rules that yield the deterministic (synthetic) labels.

Your job is to convey this to your customer. If you must, perhaps you can call the probabilities $0\%$ and $100\%$. This is legitimate, as those probabilities will correspond to events never and always happening, respectively.

If you want to use a simpler rule or one that does not require you to measure data that are expensive to measure, then that is a different story, but you do not appear to have that.

Comment: Sorry, you can correct me if I am wrong. But  I am not looking for a probability of falling into particular category..May be my English isn't that good. What I am looking for is instead of binary outcomes 1 and 0, we want to rank records based on their likelihood to achieve the target. You might say that we can again users to come up with a weighting rule or scoring mechanism but won't that he full of subjective choices when we are not able to arrive at a conclusion on that (despite having multiple sessions). So, we felt using ML would provide an objective assessment

Comment: Based on the generated probability scores, high scores indicating high likelihood and low scores indicating low likelihood...it becomes easier for users to focus on projects they want to work..

Comment: Can't Automation of the process, moving away from binary outcomes , objective and consistent assessment, scalability etc be the reasons to choose an ML approach than rule based approach?

Comment: You have the exact rules for creating the labels. All of this business about estimating tendencies instead of discrete categories and evaluating such models with proper scoring rules applies to situations where the decision boundary between the categories is unclear. In your case, you know how to predict the correct category every single time, since it is a synthetic category. Is this synthetic category a proxy for something else?

Comment: This synthetic labels/category is a proxy for ground truth...we don't have ground truth...Did I answer your question correctly?

Comment: Do you ever use the ground truth as the labels?

Comment: No, we don't have ground truth as the labels. Currently, we are running this experiement and gathering feedback from customers on whether our prediction of category (or synthetic category) is indeed the actual category that customer experiences. in real world (which will future be used as ground truth)